# HHH000362: Unable to retrieve type info result set : com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-525, SQLSTATE=51015, DRIVER=4.14.111

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have created a test Jee7 application running on Glassfish 4 accessing DB2 v10 on z/os.

I am using Hibernate

It all works as expected APART from this server warning

```
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.0.Final}
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
WARN: HHH000362: Unable to retrieve type info result set : com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-525, SQLSTATE=51015, SQLERRMC=2;DSN00000.NULLID.SYSSTAT;5359534C564C3031, DRIVER=4.14.111
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

I would rather my server startup had no errrors or warnings, how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the -525 is a missing LICENSE package on z/os `DB2LIC.SYSLIC`

From IBM DOCS

```
Resolving the problem
For connections to DB2 LUW servers this error can be ignored as it is only logged in the JCC diagnostic log (jccdiag.log) and within a driver trace and is not returned to the application. There is no impact on the application and does not cause connections to fail. 
For connections to DB2 for z/OS, this package can be created by running the db2connectactivate command that is found within the license activation package for DB2 Connect Unlimited Edition for System z. This package can be obtained from Passport Advantage.
```

Answer (score 1):

**SQLCODE=-525**

> THE SQL STATEMENT CANNOT BE EXECUTED BECAUSE IT WAS IN ERROR AT
>   BIND TIME FOR SECTION = sectno PACKAGE = pkgname CONSISTENCY TOKEN =
>   contoken

- The statement was in error when the package was bound, but the error was ignored then because the option SQLERROR (CONTINUE) was used. Since the statement contains an error, it cannot be executed.
- The statement might not be an executable statement at this location, or might only be executable by a DB2® application requester (for example, DECLARE TABLE in an application running on OS/2 causes this message).

Read more: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/n525.dita

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this, whats odd is this occurs during server startup, BEFORE i have made any client calls to my application. i have set <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />, however no SQL is shown in the log when this warning appears.